# Are there any online communities dedicated to reviewing code of lengthier projects?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I was curious if there are any communities for posting the code of more lengthy projects. I found Code Review, but it seems to be more dedicated to smaller chunks of code. I'm curious if there is anything for larger projects, a community that might consist of those who "spot check" code and maybe point out where it has flaws or can be improved. Are there any communities like this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are no Stack Exchange communities for this.

Stack Exchange has a limited size for postings. To accomodate this type of review, the amount of material that could be put in a Stack Exchange question box would have to be increased significantly.

It is doubtful that people would want to code-review entire projects just for points. Snippets are manageable; entire projects means hours of work.

But since you're willing to have your code base reviewed by third parties, you could put it on GitHub or a similar service. Then you could ask people to look at them. Clearly you cannot just post on SE and ask to "look at my GitHub", but you can put it in your profile page - or ask it in your social media.

You can still use Code Review for review of smaller parts, and take what you learn from that.

For the design side of things, you could visit [Software Engineering](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com) (formerly Programmers Stack Exchange).
Their Help Center lists that questions about requirements, architecture and design are usually on-topic.
So, you can't dump an entire project there - but if you have a question about the architecture of your project, and it's not opinion-based, you can ask it there. That's the closest that Stack Exchange can provide in terms of project-level review.

Answer (score 7):

**No.**

Code Review is the site in the SE network dealing with the review of code, *as the site name clearly states*. There is no "XL-Code Review", nor should there be one IMO.

In general, Code Review mostly focusses on Semantics, Syntax, and do's or don't do's. Applying those standards to a full project will probably end up being "a tad" more time consuming then most community members are okay with spending.

I don't know your code / project, but it's most likely possible to split it up into more "digestable" chuncks.